# Having trouble understanding how to maintain state using classes

Tags: java, oop

I'm new to using OOP, I typically just put all my code in a single class and use methods. But I want to maintain state information and think classes are the best fit but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Say I have a list of items and I want to stop when the total sum of all previous items in the list equals X(in this case 10 so it takes item 1 + 2, then 2+3.etc..until it hits the threshold 10), I can use a method to calculate it but it involves me doing the entire process all over again when all I really need to do is increment by the last item and then see if my data exceeds the threshold.  Here's my code so far but I know its not good because although it works its really just using the class as an independent method and recalculating on every loop.  My goal is to,using this structure, reduce loops if not necessary to check thresholds.

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
public class LearningClassesCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int[] data_list = new int[list.length];
        for (int current_location = 0; current_location<list.length;current_location++) {
            //can only put commands in here. Nothing above.
            Counter checker = new Counter(data_list);
            System.out.println(checker.check_data(current_location));
            for (int i =0; i<100; i++){
                if (checker.check_data(current_location) == false) {
                    break;
                }
                data_list[current_location] = (list[current_location]+1); //this is just a random function, it could be any math function I just put it in here to show that some work is being done.
            }
        }
        //its done now lets print the results
        for (Integer item : data_list) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}


class Counter {
    private int[] data_list;
    private int total_so_far;   
    // create a new counter with the given parameters
    public Counter(int[] data_list) {
        this.data_list = data_list;
        this.total_so_far = 0;
    } 

    public boolean check_data(int current_location) {   
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int total_so_far = 0;
        //System.out.println(total_so_far);
        for (int item : data_list) {
            total_so_far = item + total_so_far;
            if (total_so_far >= 10) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (total_so_far>=10) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

I don't need anyone to fix my code or anything(I want to do it myself, the code is just to give an idea of what I'm doing).  I'm more interested in the flaw in my logic and maybe a way for me to better think about designing classes so I can apply them to my own situations better.

Comment: i have no clue what you're trying to do with this.

Comment: @techjunkie.css I would be glad to clarify any specific part your having trouble understanding.

Comment: I also have no clue what you are trying to accomplish, but I would like to point out that you are declaring a local variable, total_so_far, inside your check_data method, which is hiding the total_so_far instance variable. I doubt that you meant to do this.

Comment: "Say I have a list of items and I want to stop when the total sum of all previous items in the list equals X" - stop what? Copying the items to a second list?

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend doing some basic java tutorials on classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution is that you do not update the `data_list` directly. Instead have a setter method in the `Counter` class that takes the index and value to update. It updates the value in the array and also updates a count value.

Something like this:

```
class Counter{
    private final int[] list;
    private count = 0;
    private final maxCount = 10;


    public Counter(int[] list){
       this.list = list;
    }

    public boolean updateValueAndCheckPastMax(int index, int value){
         list[index] = value;
         count += value;
         return count >= maxCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does seem like a better way but my actual program is quite large and this would cause me to change a lot of code.  Is it possible to use a class to maintain a counter of some sort and then let me know(via a method) when some condition is reached?

Comment: Yes. Write a class that maintains a counter of some sort and then lets you know (via a method) when some condition is reached. If your question is that vague don't expect a good answer. GIGO

Comment: Thanks, I'll test your advice.  Sorry for the vagueness. I typically post very specific questions because I often just want a problem fixed and move on.  In this case because I'm trying to learn I picked a problem that was more general so I could build my understanding from there.

Comment: By the way, Thank you your approach worked perfectly.  I'll hack it some more to understand more but I think I can apply the logic to other areas of my code base now.  Thanks a lot(and sorry again for the odd question), you did help me a lot with the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You are way over thinking this, and a counter class is not really necessary in this case.

I'm also interested as to why you'd be doing this line:

```
data_list[current_location] = (list[current_location]+1);
```

Do you want your data_list to be the same as list, but each value is incremented by 1?

If you are merely trying to return a sub-array of the values that are < 10, i would suggest just doing this in a for loop, and using an int as a counter.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, should have explained.  That area is just dummy work just to do something.  My real program does actual work there but for the example I just put anything random in there..could be any math function. The point of the question is to understand how I can monitor certain thresholds without recalculating any time.